# Removing whitespace from a list in python

Tags: python, list, spaces

I am currently making a cipher program in python but I can't seem to solve this one problem:

```
word = ['a', 'b', 'c']
-----enciphering process-------
message = ['d', 'e', 'f']

print message[x],
```

What I want to happen:

```
'def'
```

What actually happens:

```
'd e f'
```

I know why the spaces are there, but I can't seem to get rid of them, I've tried using strip, replace, re.sub, message(map whatever I don't remember), and "".join. Those all work with a pre-determined list but not when I don't know what the list is going to be.

Help please.

*EDIT

What I meant was something like this:

```
Word = raw_input("Enter a word  ")
Message = list(word)

w = raw_input("Enter a number  ")
w = int(w)
n = len(message)

Letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' and so on until z]

For y in range(0,n):

   For index in range(0,26):

      X = index + w

      If x > 25:
         x = x - 26

      If message[y] == letters[index]:
         print letters[x],
```

Not sure how to get rid of the spaces because I don't know what the message is gonna be

Comment: Can we see what exactly you have tried?  I feel like all those are good options.

Answer (score 5):

`print message[x],` prints the character `message[x]`, then a space (technically, a "virtual" space that gets turned into a space by the next `print` statement). If you call it in a loop, you will get `d e f`.

Instead, `print ''.join(message)`.

Comment: `sys.stdout.write()` is another option.  It probably won't make a difference here, but if `len(message)` were enormous, this approach may speed up processing time.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what is not working for you.  Here's how it looks in interactive python:

```
>>> message = ['d', 'e', 'f']
>>> print message
['d', 'e', 'f']
>>> print "".join(message)
def
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.writelines(message)
def>>>
```

Lines beginning with `>>>` are statements, other lines are output.  The last line is `def` with no newline, followed by the `>>>` input prompt.

Answer (score 0):

quick answer is

```
import sys
# ...
sys.stdout.write(letters[x])
```

but you have a problem in how you structure your code

you want to encode a message
you should apply your encoding function to that message 
for example

```
word="Hello"
encoded=''.join(map(lambda i: chr(ord(i) ^ 13), word))
print encoded
```

Comment: I would try all of your suggestions, but I have no idea what map does, lambda, or sys.stdout does. But thank you all for the help.

Comment: sys.stdout is the system standard output (it's a file object you can write directly to it). lambda is in short an anonymous function (defined inline in one line that only returns a value) maps loops over elements and pass them to the passed function (the lambda in our case)